Cannot Add JDK to PATH Environment Variable on Windows 11
I'm trying to add the JDK to the PATH environment variable on my Windows 11 machine, but I’m encountering issues. When I attempt to modify the PATH, I cannot activate the "edit" button or "delete" button to add path.
I haven’t installed any suspicious or potentially harmful software. My system is regularly updated with the latest Windows patches. Has anyone else encountered this issue? Are there specific permissions or settings that I need to adjust to resolve this?"
thank you!


Your windows profile is locked down. You would need to be a local (or domain) administrator to modify system variables. Modify the User Environment variables instead. Add JAVA_HOME point it to your JDK root. And then add %JAVA_HOME%\bin to the Path in User variables. That's from memory. Like the maid, I don't do Windows any more. Best of luck!

From Settings -> search for System environment variables.

Thanks for your contribution. Hope it works

I've fixed the tags.  There is absolutely nothing specific to Java in this question.  It is about setting environment variables in general.  (Even PATH is not Java specific.)

Try to change it in User environment variables, not System
